# Can I use my own heap in place of the priority_queue used in <boost graph library> dijkstra_shortest_paths?

Tags: graph, boost, boost-graph

I want to write a Dijkstra's algorithm, and I like to take advantage of the [boost graph library's code](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html), but I want to use my own implementation of binomial heap and heap instead of the default priority queue. This is my first time using downloaded library code, and I just couldn't figure out a way to do this. Does anyone know how to do this or if this is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how to do this or if this is impossible?

No, `dijkstra_shortest_paths` doesn't take a queue type.

That doesn't mean it's impossible. Boost's Dijkstra is an application of BFS. BFS [***does*** support custom buffer types](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/graph/doc/breadth_first_search.html#:%7E:text=UTIL%3A%20buffer(Buffer%26%20Q)).

Keep in mind that Dijkstra requires a [priority queue that supports the DECREASE-KEY operation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html#:%7E:text=priority%20queue%20that%20supports%20the%20DECREASE%2DKEY%20operation.)

The decrease-key operation can be specialized for your queue type:

```
/**
 * @brief Updates a particular value in a queue used by Dijkstra's
 * algorithm.
 *
 * This routine is called by Dijkstra's algorithm after it has
 * decreased the distance from the source vertex to the given @p
 * vertex. By default, this routine will just call @c
 * Q.update(vertex). However, other queues may provide more
 * specialized versions of this routine.
 *
 * @param Q             the queue that will be updated.
 * @param vertex        the vertex whose distance has been updated
 * @param old_distance  the previous distance to @p vertex
 */
template < typename Buffer, typename Vertex, typename DistanceType >
inline void dijkstra_queue_update(
    Buffer& Q, Vertex vertex, DistanceType old_distance)
{
    (void)old_distance;
    Q.update(vertex);
}
```

All Dijkstra invocations go through `dijkstra_shortest_paths_no_init`, which is responsible for invoking the BFS:

```
// Call breadth first search
template < class Graph, class SourceInputIter, class DijkstraVisitor,
    class PredecessorMap, class DistanceMap, class WeightMap, class IndexMap,
    class Compare, class Combine, class DistZero, class ColorMap >
inline void dijkstra_shortest_paths_no_init(const Graph& g,
    SourceInputIter s_begin, SourceInputIter s_end, PredecessorMap predecessor,
    DistanceMap distance, WeightMap weight, IndexMap index_map, Compare compare,
    Combine combine, DistZero zero, DijkstraVisitor vis, ColorMap color)
{
    typedef indirect_cmp< DistanceMap, Compare > IndirectCmp;
    IndirectCmp icmp(distance, compare);

    typedef typename graph_traits< Graph >::vertex_descriptor Vertex;

    // Now the default: use a d-ary heap
    boost::scoped_array< std::size_t > index_in_heap_map_holder;
    typedef detail::vertex_property_map_generator< Graph, IndexMap,
        std::size_t >
        IndexInHeapMapHelper;
    typedef typename IndexInHeapMapHelper::type IndexInHeapMap;
    IndexInHeapMap index_in_heap
        = IndexInHeapMapHelper::build(g, index_map, index_in_heap_map_holder);
    typedef d_ary_heap_indirect< Vertex, 4, IndexInHeapMap, DistanceMap,
        Compare >
        MutableQueue;
    MutableQueue Q(distance, index_in_heap, compare);

    detail::dijkstra_bfs_visitor< DijkstraVisitor, MutableQueue, WeightMap,
        PredecessorMap, DistanceMap, Combine, Compare >
        bfs_vis(vis, Q, weight, predecessor, distance, combine, compare, zero);

    breadth_first_visit(g, s_begin, s_end, Q, bfs_vis, color);
}
```

Your could replace the `d_ary_heap` with your own queue in your own entry point wrapper function. (You could bypass existing BGL Dijkstra algorithm entry points, or you could conceivably hack it with an overload that kicks in on your specific argument types (graph type or any of the other arguments)).

### Proof Of Concept

E.g. a proof-of-concept that arbitrarily wraps the Graph type. In hindsight it could be much easier to wrap e.g. the comparison predicate instead.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c581ed6faf5a3e1)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using G = boost::adjacency_list<>;
using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
using E = G::edge_descriptor;

namespace PoC {
    template <typename Graph> struct Wrapped : Graph {
        using Graph::Graph;
        Graph&       get()       { return *this; } 
        Graph const& get() const { return *this; } 
    };

    template <class Graph, class SourceInputIter, class DijkstraVisitor, class PredecessorMap,
              class DistanceMap, class WeightMap, class IndexMap, class Compare, class Combine,
              class DistZero, class ColorMap>
    inline void dijkstra_shortest_paths_no_init(Wrapped<Graph> const& g, SourceInputIter s_begin,
                                                SourceInputIter s_end, PredecessorMap predecessor,
                                                DistanceMap distance, WeightMap weight, IndexMap index_map,
                                                Compare compare, Combine combine, DistZero zero,
                                                DijkstraVisitor vis, ColorMap color) {
        using namespace boost;
        indirect_cmp<DistanceMap, Compare> icmp(distance, compare);

        using Vertex = typename graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor;

        // Now the default: use a d-ary heap
        boost::scoped_array<std::size_t> index_in_heap_map_holder;
        using IndexInHeapMapHelper   = detail::vertex_property_map_generator<Graph, IndexMap, std::size_t>;
        using IndexInHeapMap         = typename IndexInHeapMapHelper::type;
        using MutableQueue           = d_ary_heap_indirect<Vertex, 4, IndexInHeapMap, DistanceMap, Compare>;
        IndexInHeapMap index_in_heap = IndexInHeapMapHelper::build(g, index_map, index_in_heap_map_holder);
        MutableQueue   Q(distance, index_in_heap, compare);

        std::cerr << "SEHE WAS HERE - pretend we use different MutableQueue" << std::endl;

        detail::dijkstra_bfs_visitor<DijkstraVisitor, MutableQueue, WeightMap, PredecessorMap, DistanceMap,
                                     Combine, Compare>
            bfs_vis(vis, Q, weight, predecessor, distance, combine, compare, zero);

        breadth_first_visit(g, s_begin, s_end, Q, bfs_vis, color);
    }
}

template <typename G>
    struct boost::graph_traits<PoC::Wrapped<G>> : graph_traits<G> {};
template <typename G, typename P>
    struct boost::graph_property<PoC::Wrapped<G>, P> : graph_property<G, P> {};

int main() {
    PoC::Wrapped<G> g(10);
    add_edge(1, 3, g);
    add_edge(2, 4, g);
    add_edge(3, 2, g);
    add_edge(4, 8, g);
    add_edge(8, 3, g);

    print_graph(g);

    std::vector<V>         pred(num_vertices(g));
    std::priority_queue<V> q;
    dijkstra_shortest_paths( //
        g, 0,
        boost::predecessor_map(pred.data())                           //
            .weight_map(boost::constant_property_map<E, double>(0.0)) //
            .max_priority_queue(q)                                    //
    );
}
```

Printing, as expected:

```
0 --> 
1 --> 3 
2 --> 4 
3 --> 2 
4 --> 8 
5 --> 
6 --> 
7 --> 
8 --> 3 
9 --> 
SEHE WAS HERE - pretend we use different MutableQueue
```

### Notes/Caveat

Note: I see two reasons to report this as an issue/feature request with the library maintainers:

- the added code will depend on `detail::dijkstra_bfs_visitor`; the name implies it's not intended as public interface
- conceptually, BGL [tries to be generic with regard to algorithms ***and*** data-structures](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html#:%7E:text=Genericity%20in%20the%20Boost%20Graph%20Library); the omission of the queue from algorithm parameters could be an oversight

Comment: Note that `d_ary_heap` became default [in 2009](https://github.com/boostorg/graph/commit/4b61796e41f262f06df39aa253c56701c994be27) and the alternative [with `BOOST_GRAPH_DIJKSTRA_USE_RELAXED_HEAP` was removed in 2018](https://github.com/boostorg/graph/commit/19c23ca2555040915660918cc8a6ff2b0d49bf80). You may want to research related issues as cautionary tales.

Comment: Did you find this answer? Feedback will be much appreciated